npx supabase start Cannot find module: '../util/template'
When I run npx supabase start after npx supabase init and a few npx supabase start and npx supabase stop, Error: Cannot find module '../util/template' will occur. It is same when I run npx supabase start --ignore-health-check
My config.toml file is default.
The entire output without --debug option is below.
% npx supabase start -x storage-api
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '../util/template'
Require stack:
- /app/node_modules/knex/lib/migrations/migrate/MigrationGenerator.js
- /app/node_modules/knex/lib/migrations/migrate/Migrator.js
- /app/node_modules/knex/lib/knex-builder/make-knex.js
- /app/node_modules/knex/lib/execution/transaction.js
- /app/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js
- /app/node_modules/knex/lib/knex-builder/Knex.js
- /app/node_modules/knex/lib/index.js
- /app/node_modules/knex/knex.js
- /app/dist/database/multitenant-db.js
- /app/dist/database/index.js
- /app/dist/scripts/migrate-call.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/knex/lib/migrations/migrate/MigrationGenerator.js:2:38)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/app/node_modules/knex/lib/migrations/migrate/MigrationGenerator.js',
    '/app/node_modules/knex/lib/migrations/migrate/Migrator.js',
    '/app/node_modules/knex/lib/knex-builder/make-knex.js',
    '/app/node_modules/knex/lib/execution/transaction.js',
    '/app/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js',
    '/app/node_modules/knex/lib/knex-builder/Knex.js',
    '/app/node_modules/knex/lib/index.js',
    '/app/node_modules/knex/knex.js',
    '/app/dist/database/multitenant-db.js',
    '/app/dist/database/index.js',
    '/app/dist/scripts/migrate-call.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v20.11.1
error running container: exit 1
Try rerunning the command with --debug to troubleshoot the error.

